# JS. Массив, который возвращает букву. Азбука Морзе

Tags: javascript

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой основный вопрос - я не понимаю как вызывается такого рода массив `MORSE_CODE['.--']`, и массив ли это?
Я привык к тому, что если я вызываю какую-то функцию и она мне возвратит логическое какое-то вычисление, то вызвал бы функцию так - `MORSE_CODE(['.--'])`, т.е. передал бы функции массив в виде аргумента.
Так же при работе с JavaScript я привык, что есть массив `arr = [a, b, c]`, чтобы обратиться к каждому элементу мне нужно написать `arr[0]`, `arr[1]` или `arr[2]`.
Я не понимаю каким образом написали массив так, что при обращении к массиву  происходит возврат нужной буквы Азбуки Морзе.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Азбука кодируется не массивом а хэш-таблицей. В роли хэш-таблиц в JS выступают обычные объекты:

```js
const alphabet = {
  '.---': 'a',
  '-.--': 'b',
  '--.-': 'c',
  // и так далее
};

console.log(alphabet['--.-']); // вернёт 'с'
```

Обращение к полям объекта в JS происходит так же как и обращение к элементам массива - через квадратные скобки.